# Symfony custom form table

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I use form theme like it is explain in the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html with :

```
{% form_theme form.methodes 'form_table_layout.html.twig' %}
```

In order to have table and not "div".

My problem is :

For a normal form with "div", i use this code to modify and adapt a collection :

```
{% block _Examplebundle_methodes_entry_widget %}
```

Documentation "How to Customize a Collection Prototype" : https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/form_customization.html

It work for theme with "div" but with the theme 'form_table_layout.html.twig' it didn't work. I don't know how to custom block with the table theme.

here is a part of my code :

```
{% form_theme form.methodes 'form_table_layout.html.twig' %}

//////// Block to custom the collection/////////////
{% block _Examplebundle_methodes_entry_widget %}
 <tr>
    <td>
         {{ form_widget(form.methodeEssai) }}
         {{ form_errors(form.methodeEssai)}}
    </td>
    <td>
       {{ form_widget(form.ind, {'attr' : {'placeholder' : 'Index'}}) }}
       {{ form_errors(form.ind)}}
    </td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>z</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>r</td>
    <td>t</td>
 </tr>          
{% endblock %}
//////// End Block custom /////////////

{% block body %}
{{ form_start(form) }}
....
<table id="eagle_laboratorybundle_pvp_methodes" class="row"
                data-prototype=" 
{{form_widget(form.methodes.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"
                data-index="{{ form.methodes|length }}">
<thead>
     <tr>
         <th>x</th>
         <th>y</th>
         <th>z</th>
         <th>a</th>
         <th>r</th>
         <th>e</th>
         <th>t</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
       {{ form_widget(form.methodes) }}
       {{ form_errors(form.methodes) }}
 </tbody> 
</table>


/// Some JS etc...///
```

So with the block _entry_widget i expected to custom rows of my table like it permit to custom div when i'm using original layout theme.

Someone know how to custom form rendering with table theme ?